# How to set maxdate in datepicker 365/366(leap year) based on selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Given a start date how to find the end date which have 365 or 366 days based on the leap year in javascript
For start date one date picker is used and for end date one date picker is used.

I tried like based on year we can find, it is leap year or not. But while considering both start date and end date it is not clear

This is directly passing days as 365 but it should differ based on leap year

```
tripenddate(dateText, 365)

function tripenddate(dateText, days) {
    midate = dateText
    var mmm = midate.split("/");
    var nnn = mmm[1] + "/" + mmm[0] + "/" + mmm[2];
    var someDate = new Date(nnn);
    someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + days);
    var dateFormated = someDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10).split("-");
    mxdate = dateFormated[2] + "/" + dateFormated[1] + "/" + dateFormated[0];
    $('.traveldateendinput').datepicker('option', 'minDate', midate);
    $('.traveldateendinput').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', mxdate);
}
```

Expected output is, in the tripenddate function we should pass days as 365/366 based on selected start date (by satisfying logic leap year or not)

Comment: What is the usecase? It is rare to need to know the number of days in a year. Can you please click the `[<>]` snippet editor and give us a [mcve]

Comment: Why not just `var minDate = new Date(nnn), maxDate = new Date(nnn); maxDate.setFullYear(maxDate.getFullYear()+1);`